# Site rendering incorrectly when uploaded to FTP

Tags: html, css, ftp

I have a strange problem, that when I upload my website to server it gets rendered all incorrectly - positioning, script etc. problems. The same site works perfectly on the same browser when run locally from my hard drive.

Screenshot when run locally:
[image: Screenshot when run locally]

Screenshot from web:
[image: Screenshot from web]

Comment: Update: site available at [link](http://graphicsdev.s-interier-design.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the browsers console and you will find out, that `css/jquery.fullpage.css` is missing. This might explain the render problems. It might be that you simply forgot to upload this file, but it might also that you've uploaded a similar file instead. Please not that contrary to Windows file names on UNIX or Linux systems are case-sensitive, that is `jquery.fullpage.css` is not the same as `Jquery.fullpage.CSS` and if you've uploaded the last it will not be foud when you are trying to access the first. This might explain the difference between testing on a local Windows system and rolling out to a remote UNIX/Linux system.

Comment: This indeed was the problem there. I corrected it and the site now works flawlessly, however only in Safari and mobile Safari. The same issue persists in Chrome and Firefox. I've also doublechecked this with consoles in both of the browsers and it doesn't list any error. The site is now located at rev.stunning.graphics

Comment: This is then probably because different browsers render things differently. This is especially the case if you use very new features (some CSS3) or browser specific stuff (i.e. -webkit etc). But it should not make any difference between chrome remote and chrome locally, or does it?

Comment: Issue solved now. It appears `position: fixed` renders differently in Safari than the other browsers. Changing it to `position: absolute` did the trick.